# wp_nav_menu doesn't seem to work on custom post type pages

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, navigation

I'm working on something someone else set up, and on the index page, the nav appears, but on custom post type pages, it does not.

The nav menu:

```
 wp_nav_menu([
                'menu'              => 'Primary Menu',
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                'depth'             => 3,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'a',
                'container_id'      => 'b',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
        ]);
```

I've seen it suggested that I place this in a function and use an if statement to do *something* and on other pages, have this nav function. My problem is that I don't know what to put in the `wp_nav_menu()` for the custom post type pages, so it appears.

The URL for instance looks like: `http://example.com/product-category/thing/`

Comment: If you've verified that the function is present but outputs nothing, the likely culprit is some poorly targeted code modifying the query for menu items causing nothing to be returned.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to truly answer this without knowing what the theme templates look like for custom post types

Answer (score 0):

You can just add these parameters in array variable and pass this to `wp_nav_menu()` Like:

```
function get_menu_params(){

    $defaults = array(
        'menu'              => 'Primary Menu',
        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
        'depth'             => 3,
        'container'         => 'div',
        'container_class'   => 'a',
        'container_id'      => 'b',
        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
        'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
        'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
    );                          
    return $defaults;
}
```

and call it on the custom post type pages like below:

```
wp_nav_menu( get_menu_params( ) );
```

This will help you.

Comment: I probably miscommunicated. This I get. The nav menu displays on everything but custom post type archive pages. `wp_get_nav_menu_object` also returns null. I can get an *Add Menu* link where the nav should be, but that is it.

Comment: Then I Think may be issue is with these two parameters, 
        `'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
        'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()`

Check it by removing these two parameters